# Connection to chatbot from word

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, ms-word, connection

I am trying to connect to Bing chatbot with macro from Word using Selenium.

The edge browser opens but is blocked by its security features. It detects automation software.
The same happens with Firefox and Chrome.

What I am looking for is a connection to the chatbot as if I were using a browser. The browser does not have to open physically. Another way to connect would be using a key, however, that would require payment which I would like to avoid.

How are such connections established from word?

```
Sub BingChatbot()
    Dim driver As New WebDriver
    Dim botResponse As String
    
    'Set Edge driver path
    driver.Start "edge", "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\edgedriver.exe"
    
    'Navigate to Bing Chat website
    driver.Get "https://www.bing.com/chat"
    
    'Wait for page to load
    driver.Wait 5000
    
    'Find and click on chat input box
    driver.FindElementById("chatInput").Click
    
    'Enter message to send to bot
    driver.FindElementById("chatInput").SendKeys "Hello"
    
    'Find and click on send button
    driver.FindElementById("chatSendButton").Click
    
    'Wait for bot response
    driver.Wait 5000
    
    'Get bot response
    botResponse = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='rspText']").Text
    
    'Print bot response to immediate window
    Debug.Print "Bot Response: " & botResponse
    
    'Quit the driver
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```